# Hide specific div class when the size of object is larger

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have the following problem. My page is loading swf objects. Sometimes their size is less than 700 px, sometimes larger than 700px. For larger objects I would like to hide the right sidebar and make the content width larger.

Right now my CSS is:

```
.content-body .main {
    float: left;
    width: 72%;
}
```

For larger objects I would like to have it in this way:

```
.content-body .main {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}
```

I have 2 separated files: first one is to generate the object's size and the second one is to display the swf. So, for the first file I need to do something like this:

```
if ($obSize > 700) {
?>
<style type="text/css">content-body .main {
float:left;
 width:75%;
}</style>
<?php
}
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone help me? Much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a dot `.` to select `content-body` class in your css:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*  ↓ here  */
    .content-body .main {
        float:left;
        width:75%;
    }
</style>
```